# Xtext: Creating "JavaDoc" comments with @annotations

Tags: parameters, documentation, comments, javadoc, xtext

I'm using MultiLineCommentDocumentationProvider to allow JavaDoc-like comments for entities (using /** */).

However, if I use @ (annotation) for some parameter it doesn't get bold like in Java and doesn't even break the line when mouse hovering.

Is there a way I can use extend Xtext's MultiLineCommentDocumentationProvider to support the above?

Example

```
/** some description 
@myParam param description */
someEntity(Param myParam) {..}
```

Should look like when mouse hovering on someEntity (or on some reference to it):

some description

**myParam:**  param description

Instead of (currently it looks like):

some description @myparam param description

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Christian's advice, I changed 'MyDSLMultiLineCommentDocumentationProvider' this way:

```
    @Override
    public String getDocumentation(EObject o) {
        String returnValue = findComment(o);
        String returnValueWithAnnotations = getAnnotatedDocumentation(returnValue);
        return getTextFromMultilineComment(returnValueWithAnnotations);
    }

    private String getAnnotatedDocumentation(String returnValue) {
      boolean isFirstAnnotationFound = false;
      StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("");
    String[] splitted = returnValue.trim().split(" +");
    for (int i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++)
    {
      if (splitted[i].charAt(0) == '@')
      {
        if (! isFirstAnnotationFound)
        {
          result.append("<br><b>Parameters:</b>");
          isFirstAnnotationFound = true;
        }
        result.append("<br>"); //new line
        result.append("<b>"); //bold
        result.append(splitted[i].substring(1) + " "); // do not include "@"
        result.append("</b>");
      }
      else
      {
        result.append(splitted[i] + " ");
      }
    }
    String resultString = result.toString();
    return resultString.substring(0, resultString.length()-1); // getting rid of the strange "/" in the end
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

this is not a default feature of `MultiLineCommentDocumentationProvider`. you may use `XbaseHoverDocumentationProvider`/`XbaseHoverProvider` or at least let you inspire by it.